"Look at the giraffes." VS "Look at all the giraffes."
Someone is just walking into a lodge booked for a holiday in a safari park with wild animals in close vicinity. And when he shows the viewers inside of the lodge, rooms, amenities, etc, he notices that one of the room's window looks over right where giraffes live. So he is suprised and says:
"Look at all the giraffes."
I wonder why he didn't simply say "Look at the giraffes.", but added the word "all" to the sentence. Both would mean the same.
Then I thought about it, and maybe "all the giraffes" sounds more emphatic than "the giraffes." Is that right?

I think this question can be answered easily by translating the sentences into your native languages.

@user1176409, That is why I asked, I wanted to see the difference when I translate both of them. When I translate "Look at the giraffes", it is easy, but when I translate "Look at all the giraffes", it doesn't sound idiomatic in my language, "the giraffes" and "all the giraffes" are both plural, and because "all" refers to "all of the giraffes", it does not sound good when you translate it by using the equivalence of "all" in my language. Because when you tell somebody to look at them, you know that they would anyway look at all of them, regardless you say "ALL" or not.

Look at the giraffes highlights the fact that there are any giraffes at all to be seen.
By contrast, Look at all the giraffes suggests that it is not the existence of giraffes that is so significant, but the large number of them. Another way to express this idea is Look at how many giraffes there are.

I wonder if he had said "Look at all these giraffes.", would it have meant the same as "Look at all the giraffes"?

@Yunus: I suggest you look up "these" (and "this", "that", etc) in a grammar book.
